# The specific endpoint doesn't work (404) on all languages except default one (en) on the latest Joomla after upgrade

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I was helping my friend to upgrade old Joomla (3.3.4) to the latest one. After a lot of fixes, we faced a problem with a custom module. For the English language, everything works fine but as soon as I change language, that specific endpoint results in a 404 error. Problem is that Joomla adds the language prefix to the URL (de for German) which results in an error.

I don't have much knowledge of Joomla and I don't know where to start... It is getting really frustrating because I spend the last three days debugging it.

Does someone know where to issue can be and can someone point me in the right direction?

Best regards.

Comment: Which module causes the 404 error? Where did Joomla add the language prefix to the URL? (example.com/de/ ?) - try to disable SEF for searching, possibly the module does not interpret `language=de` correctly any more?

Comment: Can you please help me with the module name and URL which getting 404 error?And I would suggest that please check in the admin if you created a home menu (default) for German language.

Comment: @TomKuschel Problem was in the plugin/module order. Once I move plugin that is responsible for custom routing at the end everything worked well.

Comment: Good to hear it's working now.